# Is there a better way for calling methods in a managing view controller from a managed view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

In the apps I've developed so far, I've always had a `UIViewController` in charge of presenting other `UIViewController`s to display transitions in the UI. Whenever I've had a "managed" view controller call a method in the "managing" view controller, I've had to ensure that I had a reference to the managing controller inside of the managed controller.

For example:
If I have a `UIViewController` called `MainController` that is in charge of managing other `UIViewController`s in my application's UI, and `MainController` creates 2 controllers for presentation. Called `SubController1` and `SubController2` respectively. If `SubController1` is finished and `MainController` needs to display `SubController2`, I've always set a `MainController` reference variable inside of `SubController1` so that it could communicate the change to `MainController`. This means that whenever `MainController` creates `SubController1` it has to set `SubController1`'s `MainController` reference variable to `self`.

Should I be worried about memory usage with this method of communications? Would I be better off using notifications for this kind of behavior? The major benefit I've found with the method I'm using now is it makes it incredibly easy to share information between view controllers if necessary. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use customDelegate or NSNotificationsCenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling changes, actions, or user interaction in other views is the essential use case of [delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).  The best practice is to have the main controller be the delegate of the first/second view controller, and then as events happen in the child controllers, they call certain methods on their delegates, which can then take any necessary action.

Passing references the way you describe won't have a noticeable memory impact, however it does very tightly couple your code to the `MainController`, which should be avoided.  You should strive for flexibility to handle potential changes in the future.  What happens if you transition to a universal app and the iPad UI has a vastly different structure?  With delegates, you only need to ensure that the contract between the controllers is intact, but are free to change any of the underlying implementation details.

Other options for keeping values/state in sync between views are:

- [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) - best used for data
- [Key-Value Observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) - best used for data
- `NSNotification`s sent through [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - best used for actions